# Regex in a Batch file: I want to extract the number after my match

Tags: regex, batch-file, regex-group

I have a requirement where in a log file I have to search for a string "ABCD.exe Score=755" and then find what is the number after "Score=", number will change. This I have to do through a Batch file.

Content of the file I am searching

```
ScanFolder\ABCD.exe score=755 analyzer=Cloud prevScore=0 IsInArchive=False
```

From the below code I am getting output as "755 analyzer", whereas the result should be just "755"

```
@echo off
setlocal
find "ABCD.exe score=" 2023-02-22.log > ABCD.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I "score=" ABCD.txt') do set "scanScore=%%a"  
echo Score is: %scanScore%   
endlocal
```

Comment: Change `tokens=2 delims==" ` to `tokens=3 delims== " ` which will include space as a delimiter. You then need the third token.

Comment: @Magoo When I give delims== " It doesn't account the '=' as delimiter but just a space as delimiter. And then it give the first word before which there is space.

Comment: It shouldn't. That doesn't mean it isn't. Now that your question has been edited, it fits SO's "rules". Perhaps you should delete this question and re-post it. Unfortunately, having a closed question reopened is theoretically possible, but practically extremely unlikely. It would assist if you were to post the actual response (eg `yielded "score"`) rather than describing it (`first word before which there is space`). You should also check that your batch file is saved as ANSI, and that the "space" truly is a space & not a TAB. Output the `abcd` command to a file & examine it with a hex-viewer.

Comment: There can be used after `@echo off` and `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` the command line `if exist "2023-02-22.log" for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims== " %%G in ("2023-02-22.log") do if /I "%%~nxG" == "abcd.exe" if /I "%%~H" == "score" set "scanScore=%%I"` to get the value of interest assigned to the environment variable `scanScore` to use on the next command lines before the batch file ends with `endlocal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

for /F "tokens=3 delims== " %%a in ('findstr /I "score=" q75543943.txt') do set "scanScore=%%a"  
echo Score is: +%scanScore%+

:: another method

SET /p "line="<q75543943.txt
SET "line=%line:*score=%"
SET "scanscore="

:checkloop
IF "%line:~1,1%" geq "0" IF "%line:~1,1%" leq "9" SET "scanscore=%scanscore%%line:~1,1%"&SET "line=%line:~1%"&GOTO checkloop
echo Score is: +%scanScore%+

GOTO :EOF
```

It would appear that the whitespace characters may not be <kbd>Space</kbd> as the first of these options is reported as failing. Thos characters may be <kbd>Tab</kbd> or perhaps the output string is Unicode. OP should use a hex editor to check the actual ASCII value of the character following the `5`.

The second method should work by first deleting the part of the string read into `line` that precedes the string `score`, leaving `=755?analyzer...`.

So, use a loop and examine the *second* character in that string (since it has a `=` at the start initially) and string it to the result variable if it is numeric, then delete the first character of `line` and repeat until the mysterious character which is non-space and non-numeric is found.

I've used a different filename because I maintain my responses with their individual data.

Also, I've enclosed the `echo`ed responses in a bracket of `+` characters to show that there are no stray spaces in the results.